# Json Response in php this format

Tags: php, json, database

I need output like this format in php from the database:

```
{"data":[{"batch_no":"123"},{"batch_no":"124"}]}
```

Please advise me.

Comment: use json_encode function

Comment: at-least try something then put question

Comment: $batch_no=123; and $batch_no=124;
    $sqlk =<<<EOF
 
 SELECT batch_no FROM ddhs_receipt_entry  where dvn_cd ='$hud' and batch_no='$batch_no'; 
EOF;


 
$jsonData = array();
$jsonData[]=$batch_no;
$main = array('data'=>$jsonData);
echo json_encode($main);

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    array("batch_no"=>"123"),
    array("batch_no"=>"124"),
);
var_dump(json_encode(array("data" => $data)));
```

Comment: batch number is dymanic (one or more don't fixed it's from thd DB)

Comment: That is a bit different question on how you prepare your data.
Let's imagine you are fetching it from MySQL

    `$data = array();
    $resource = mysql_query("SELECT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }`